Interpolating credit migration matrix
I have a 8x8 credit ratings matrix. {Aaa, Aa, A, Bbb, Bb, B, C, Default}. I want to expand it to 21x21 by adding ratings (+ves and -ves).
How should I approach it? The diagonal elements in the original matrix has highest probabilities will this be retained in the expanded matrix?

Not exactly sure, but I have some CR experience. Personally the neighbouring ratings should have the highest transition probabilities i.e. Aa to Aa+ and Aa- should be higher than Aa to A. Another important thing is that Aa to Default tends to be higher than Aa to C.

Out of curiosity: Did you make any progress so far?

Because these are discrete data and not continuous, interpolation may give you spurious results. For example, look at the sparsity of this transition matrix from Moody's covering 2016-17. And to be precise, if you are talking about "+ves and -ves" as in AA- or BBB+, best not to mix up Moody's rating format (Aaa, Aa1, Aa2, Aa3,..., Baa1, Baa2, Baa3,...) with S&P/Fitch (AAA, AA+, AA, AA-,...).
